# How to copy Hbase data to local file system (external drive)

Tags: file, hadoop, hbase

I want to have a backup of hbase data that is in hdfs. I have an external drive ( usb hard disk). How can i copy data from hbase to my drive. I have used a command like

bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Drive export table /media/.../mydrive.

but what actually is done, that a new directory in hdfs with path /media/.../mydrive is created and nothing is save in my external hard. Why is this issue. Is there a way to inform that data should be saved in my external driver other than the command, i used above.

Please reply

Answer (score 0):

If data is in hdfs you can use below commands to copy data from hdfs to local and then from local system, you can do what ever you want to do with data.

```
hadoop fs -get path_of_hdfs_system_where_your_data_is  path_of_local_file_system
```

For example:

```
hadoop fs -get /user/hive/warehouse/rocky.db/test5_bucket/000002_0 /home/yarn
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/hive/warehouse/rocky.db/test5_bucket/000002_0 /home/yarn
```

Comment: I need to copy data with hbase commands because in later I have to import table back that I exported first. It is not possible with hadoop commands. I can export or import data but when I export data back to hbase, nothing appeared. So its not the write answer

Comment: You did not specify that you want to again load in hbase , you said you want to take backup from hbase to external .Import can be  used , Import is a utility that will load data that has been exported back into HBase. Invoke via:

$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>

To import 0.94 exported files in a 0.96 cluster or onwards, you need to set system property "hbase.import.version" when running the import command as below:
import for your use. for e.g:
$ bin/hbase -Dhbase.import.version=0.94 org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>

Comment: Brother your above guide is correct but first I have to export data. method you informed above is not valid as I has discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909132/how-to-import-export-hbase-data-via-hdfs-hadoop-commands      So please read my question statement of both questions carefully. Then answer. Thanks