# How to import/export hbase data via hdfs (hadoop commands)

Tags: hadoop, hbase, local-files

I have saved my crawled data by nutch in Hbase whose file system is hdfs. Then I copied my data (One table of hbase) from hdfs directly to some local directory by command

```
hadoop fs -CopyToLocal /hbase/input ~/Documents/output
```

After that, I copied that data back to another hbase (other system) by following command

```
hadoop fs -CopyFromLocal ~/Documents/input /hbase/mydata
```

It is saved in hdfs and when I use `list` command in hbase shell, it shows it as another table i.e 'mydata' but when I run `scan` command, it says there is no table with 'mydata' name.

What is problem with above procedure?
 In simple words:

1. I want to copy hbase table to my local file system by using a hadoop command
2. Then, I want to save it directly in hdfs in another system by hadoop command
3. Finally, I want the table to be appeared in hbase and display its data as the original table

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to export the table from one hbase cluster and import it to another, use any one of the following method:

**Using Hadoop**

- Export

  ```
  $ bin/hadoop jar <path/to/hbase-{version}.jar> export \
       <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]
  ```

  ***NOTE:*** Copy the output directory in hdfs from the source to destination cluster
- Import

  ```
  $ bin/hadoop jar <path/to/hbase-{version}.jar> import <tablename> <inputdir>
  ```

Note: *Both outputdir and inputdir are in hdfs.*

**Using Hbase**

- Export

  ```
  $ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export \
     <tablename> <outputdir> [<versions> [<starttime> [<endtime>]]]
  ```
- Copy the output directory in hdfs from the source to destination cluster
- Import

  ```
  $ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import <tablename> <inputdir>
  ```

  Reference: [Hbase tool to export and import](http://hbase.apache.org/book/ops_mgt.html#export)

Comment: I think you do not read my qustion carefully. I said "I want to copy hbase table to my local file system by using hadoop command", info you inform,

Comment: What do you mean by copying hbase table to local filesystem? You can always use hadoop's copyToLocal command on the files in hdfs related to a table, but there is no use in doing that. If you are planning to copy the table to another cluster you have to use any of the above mentioned method. Even in the above mentioned way you have to copy the exported files to local filesystem and copy it to another cluster.

Comment: I want to have a backup of my crawled data to external drive( usb hard disk) so that in case of machine failure I can rebuild my cluster. or in future if I have to adop new version og hadoop etc. then I need it

Comment: Then you can export and take a backup of that. If you just copy the files related to the table, you can't rebuild the cluster with it.

Comment: export command when I use, It create a directory in hdfs where is export data rather in local file system. My data is near 200GB

Comment: Yeah! export will trigger a map-reduce job and the output will be in hdfs. But there is no use in just copying the files related to that table directly from hdfs without exporting, you can't import/recreate the tables again since there is no meta information available with it. I am not sure whether we can give a local filesystem directory for mapreduce output .

Comment: @Nanda - was the `bin/hadoop` option done with an old version of Hadoop/Hbase, maybe?  In a modern HBase (at least 0.96) there's not one main jar, and no jar with a name like `hbase-{version}.jar`.  And the jars provided all seem to want a classname as the first argument, not just `export`.

Comment: Once you have the files in hdfs, use the "hdfs dfs -get /path/in/hdfs/" to get the files onto your local filesystem.

Comment: how to use the start time and end time option in Export utility?

Answer (score 8):

If you can use the Hbase command instead  to backup hbase tables you can use the Hbase  ExportSnapshot Tool which copies the hfiles,logs and snapshot metadata to other filesystem(local/hdfs/s3) using a map reduce job.

- Take snapshot of the table

  `$ ./bin/hbase shell
  hbase> snapshot 'myTable', 'myTableSnapshot-122112'`
- Export to the required file system

  `$ ./bin/hbase class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.snapshot.ExportSnapshot -snapshot MySnapshot -copy-to fs://path_to_your_directory`

You can export it back from the local file system to hdfs:///srv2:8082/hbase and run the restore command from hbase shell to recover the table from the snapshot.

```
 $ ./bin/hbase shell
 hbase> disable 'myTable'
 hbase> restore_snapshot 'myTableSnapshot-122112'
```

Reference:[Hbase Snapshots](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops.snapshots.html)