# How to export schema of hbase

Tags: hbase

Is there any command or way to export Hbase table schema with or without data, I followed below one but it is exporting only data not table schema. Please share details if you have found anything related to exporting the schema of Hbase table.

[this is the link i followed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909132/how-to-import-export-hbase-data-via-hdfs-hadoop-commands)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to export the schema like RDBMS, but you can describe using hbase shell:

```
hbase-shell> describe '<tablename>'
```

If you have Apache Phoenix configured, you can run the similar commands to get the schema

Another way is to run in non-interactive way via shell:

```
echo "describe '<tablename>'" | hbase shell -n
```