# Hbase export not going to copy to local file system

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have some data in hbase table. I have to take its backup. I am using 0.94.18 version. Now I have used following command for export.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export hbasetable /home/user/backup/
```

Now what happened actually is that data is copied to hdfs with exactly same path as I given. I am expecting this should copy to my local file system, but its not.

Where is the problem ?
Second how to backup table schema also in hbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your answer, take a look at [How to copy Hbase data to local file system (external drive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906577/how-to-copy-hbase-data-to-local-file-system-external-drive)

Since the data is in hadoop, you just need to copy from hadoop to local system.

As for the second par, the good old docs do the tricks: http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops.backup.html

Basically they are telling two solutions: either do the backup with the system offline, or use another cluster to hold a backup of your live system.

Comment: Not complete answer but enough (You have not guided about schema backup)